# Limit Python's Capacity per Thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I found a [tutorial about using multithreading in Python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) and looked at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html).

Although the examples work, some questions came up.

In JavaScript, an infinite loop like

```
while (true) {
    console.log("I'm trapped in an infinite loop!"); // JavaScript nearly crashes.
}
```

breaks my browser execution and I can only escape by terminating the process. In Python, though, an infinite loop works fine. I can stop it at any time. This even works combined with other threads:

I thought that an infinite loop would be the most exhausting task of all. If this was right, it would imply that Python takes care of exhausting threads so that other threads do not stop.

*This is my question: How does Python assign capacity to its underlying threads?*

```
try:
   # How much capacity will thread 1 get?
   thread.start_new_thread( very_exhausting_task, ("Thread-1", ) )
   # How much capacity will thread 2 get?
   thread.start_new_thread( another_very_exhausting_task, ("Thread-2", ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"
while 1:
   pass
```

Comment: You need to clarify "How can I control capacity?" The sites format supports a single question per post. So asking multiple questions - which can each have a different answer, and whos expertise in answering can come from different users, should be split into multiple questions - each focusing on their own part. Your questions seem primarily opinion-based, opinionated answers that cause discussion and debate are also not a fit for this site. I recommend you do some independent research and return with a solid question. Or come to the [Python Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)

Comment: You seem to be missing a basic understanding of threading and scheduling concepts. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29 to get started; but to answer this question in depth a good book or paper on OSes and scheduling would be needed. Your question of how capacity is assigned makes little sense - the python interpreter gives the thread some CPU time and breaks out of it with an interrupt; this is repeated unless the thread finishes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I removed unnecessary questions and focused on my main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "capacity" of a thread is really more of a consequence of design decisions related to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) and the characteristics of your workload.

If you aren't familiar with the GIL, this lock makes it so that only a single thread may make use of the interpreter at any given time.   This is most detrimental to threading of pure Python code (including any libraries used).  While there can be many OS threads, only a single thread will effectively run during a given time slice.

This also affects C extensions that must work with Python objects.  However, extensions can get around this limitation by releasing the GIL when doing I/O-bound work (talking on the network, etc) or when doing heavy processing that does not require Python objects.

I suggest you start with looking into https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock and reading these slide decks: http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf and http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf

You'll find details about some cooperative multitasking aspects (voluntarily releasing the GIL) coupled with preemption of GIL ownership (running past an allotted number of instructions). The latter is tunable (see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setcheckinterval)